# How to fix btrfs build error?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, python, btrfs

I build btrfs-prog on ubuntu 16.04. I get the following error message.

```
checking for PYTHON... no
configure: error: Package requirements (python-3.6) were not met:

No package 'python-3.6' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables PYTHON_CFLAGS
and PYTHON_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

Comment: Looks like the messages are hinting that you need to install Python.  But maybe you could just install `btrfs-progs` or `btrfs-tools` from the normal Ubuntu repo?

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same error compiling btrfs on 18.04, you need to install the python3 developer package: `sudo apt install libpython3-dev`

I was able to progress to 'make' afterwards, just re-run `./configure`.

For 'make' to succeed, you may also have to `sudo apt install python3-setuptools`, unless installed already for other dev work.